# Logs Only Write to EMR stderr/stdout with non-zero exit code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a piece of code in Scala which uses log4j to do logging.

I have a few conditions upon which I want to log some information to the stderr/stdout of the EMR.

If I have a non-zero exit code it will log it:

```
if (args.length != 2) {
  log.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
  log.error("Expecting 2 args. Usage: ...")
  System.exit(4)
}
```

However if I just have regular logging it does not show:

```
log.setLevel(Level.INFO)
log.info("This is my log")
```

I thought that perhaps this was because it only logs the errors in the EMR and tried the following:

```
log.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
log.error("This is my log")
```

With no luck.

It seems the logs are only written with a non-zero exit code.

I believe they are probably writing somewhere outside the log file. Is there any way to make it so that they do write where I am expecting them too?

Comment: Have you tried to enable immediateFlush via the properties file`log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true`?

Comment: Why do you call `log.setLevel` before each logging invocation? Normally you don't need to change log level from the code. 
Could you try to remove `setLevel` statements?
Who knows what happens to the logging system if log level is repeatedly changed probably from multiple threads.

Comment: @cronoik I will give that a try tomorrow

Comment: @simpadjo I am calling it to ensure the log is where I wanted it after originally not including it. It is a single threaded scala process so that should not be the issue.

Comment: @cronoik this unfortunately did not make a difference. This is what I have in properties file:

`log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n`